# What is the "problem of adaptive estimation" that necessitate the development of honest tree?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, causality

My question is about the [Athey & Imbens (2016) paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/113/27/7353.full.pdf). Even though this paper develops honest tree to estimate heterogeneous treatment effect (HTE), in this question I'm only asking about the earlier & simpler section where the honest tree is used in the prediction setting, i.e. to predict conditional average $E(Y_i|X_i = x)$.

1. The paper claims that, even in the prediction setting, the estimate is biased because of

> the problem of adaptive estimation, which is that spurious extreme
> values of $Y_i$ are likely to be placed into the same leaf as other
> extreme values by the algorithm $\pi(.)$, and thus the sample means
> (in sample $S^{tr}$) of the elements of $\pi(S^{tr})$ are more extreme
> than they would be in an independent sample

This argument makes intuitive sense. But if the "problem of adaptive estimation" is real, why does it not affect the predictive ability of the conventional CART? Is that because conventional CART aims to minimize MSE but doesn't guarantee unbiased conditional average estimates?

2. In next sentence, the paper says that

> the problem of adaptive estimation shows up in the poor coverage
> properties of confidence intervals relative to the honest methods.

So does adaptive estimation lead to bias or invalid CI? Or both? If invalid CI, where do the authors prove that?